# How to turn an object around and move into the opposite direction?

Tags: java

Considering out of bounds position is 6 and -6.

I want to make the ship turn around and move in the opposite direction.

This is the code I have.. It is still not working 100% how I want it. I am curious to see if anyone
had any ideas how do improve.
Here is the logic of my code.

```
//If the ship hits a boundary it turns around and moves in the opp.
//direction. To do this, the ship's velocty should be flipped from a 
//negative into a positive number, or from pos to neg if boundary
//is hit.

//if ship position is -5 at velocity -1 new ship pos is -6
//if ship position is -6 at velocity -1 new ship velocity is +1
//                                      new ship position is +5
```

Here is my code:

```
public void move() 
{
    position = velocity + position;

    if (position > 5)
    {
        velocity = -velocity;
    }
    else if (position < -5)
    {
        velocity = +velocity;
    }
}
```

Comment: You logic looks a bit flawed. If the position is **-6** and the velocity is **-1**, to start moving in the opposite direction, you new position should be **-5** (and not **+5** ) and the velocity **+1**.

Comment: This does nothing `velocity = +velocity;` perhaps you meant `velocity = -velocity;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code `velocity = +velocity;` will not change a negative velocity into a positive velocity. What this will do is equivalent to multiplying velocity with `+1` which does not change the sign.

To flip the sign of velocity when going out of bounds you need to always multiply `-1`.

It's not very clear what the bounds are so below I assume that they are 6 and -6.

```
position += velocity;
//make sure the ship cannot go further than the bounds
//but also make sure that the ship doesn't stand still with large velocities
if (position > 6)
{
    velocity = -velocity;
    position = 6;
}
if (position < -6)
{
    velocity = -velocity;
    position = -6;
}
```

Comment: it should never reach position 6 or -6... as they are out of bound.

Comment: @Gianmarco Oh okay. In that case just do the update after the if condition and change the if bounds. I'll edit.

Comment: as I did in my answer, I think

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
public void move() 
    {
    //first check where the next move will be:
    if ((position + velocity) > 5 || (position + velocity) < -5){

        // Here we change direction (the velocity is multiplied for -1)
        velocity *= -1;

    }

    position += velocity;
}
```

Comment: Well this will still jump outside of the bounds after you've flipped the velocity. Consider for example a velocity of 6 and a position 0. You would go to -6 which is outside of the bounds.

Comment: we can't know if the velocity should be any value, I think that velocity is as saying direction. Maybe I am wrong, in that case your answer will do it. +1

Answer (score 0):

When it hits a boundary, multiply velocity by -1.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your logic looks a bit flawed. If the position is **-6** and the velocity is **-1**, to start moving in the opposite direction, you new position should be **-5** (and not **+5** ) and the velocity **+1**.

Also, you need to invert the sign of your velocity whenever your position hits the boundary conditions.

```
public void move() {
    if (Math.abs(position + velocity) > 5) { // Check for boundary conditions
        velocity *= -1;
    }
    position = position + velocity; // position += velocity;
}
```

Comment: 6 is out of bound, i think It should not reach out of bound position but change velocity before..

Comment: @Gianmarco - In that case, we just need to put the `if` before updating the position!

Comment: yep, as I did in my answer :) i think

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to change direction you need to flip the sign.  This is the same a `* -1` or negating it.

```
public void move() {    
    // prevent it jumping through the wall.
    if (Math.abs(position + velocity) > 5)
        velocity = -velocity;

    position += velocity;
}
```

Comment: this will not work, because actually the position will be 6, before the velocity is changed.. and that's out of bound

Comment: @Gianmarco Can you check what I have again.  I changed it so that the velocity is changed before the position is changed.

Comment: why not multiply for -1 ?

Comment: @Gianmarco Multiplication is more expensive than negation.  For this use case, it doesn't matter.

Comment: really is more expensive?

Comment: @Gianmarco About 3 clock cycles instead of 1. :P Like I said, not worth worrying about.